# Python pandas list/string search - place matching value in dataframe

Tags: python, string, list, pandas

I am conducting partial string search in a df against a list - I need create a new column in the df and result the matching values from the list. I tried a few things I found on SO and elsewhere, but I can't seem to get the matching values only. Here's the basic set up

```
df
index items
0     grape
1     apple
2     cat, dog 
3     dog, other
```

Desired output:

```
df
index items      status count matching_values
0     grape      False   0     NaN 
1     apple      True    1     apple
2     cat, dog   True    2     cat, dog
3     dog, other True    1     dog
```

Here's the list for matching:

```
myList = ['apple,' 'orange', 'cat', 'dog']
matchList = '|'.join(myList)
```

Here's what's working:

```
df['status'] = df['items'].str.lower().str.contains(matchList)  # works
df['count'] = df['items'].str.lower().str.count(matchList)  # works
```

Can't get this to work:

```
df['matching_values'] = ?? #this should place only the matching values from the list into this new column
```

I have tried the following (and other variations of these) - no luck - this just puts the entire list in the cell:

```
if df['Status'].any() == True:
    df['List Match'] = matchList
else:
    df['List Match'] = "No Match"
```

And, I thought if I could get the matching location from the list, I could match it that way - no luck here either - this enters '0', the index location - which makes sense:

```
df.loc[df[items].str.lower().str.contains(matchList), 'List Match'] = matchList.index(matchList) # doesn't work
```

I also tried retrieving only the matching values from the original `items` column - it also copies over all cell contents.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain index 2 of your expected output.  How did you get 'cat and dog' in items?

Comment: @ScottBoston - re the "cat and dog" in items on index - that's the raw data - sorry just realized that I left that out in the df description at top.  Can't seem to edit my question, will fix if it allows me. The output here should match the list with the raw data, which has "cat and dog", thus should return corresponding values from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that all of the strings in the column `items` are separated by a comma (if not, we'll need to re-work the solution.  **Update**: I re-worked the solution to replace whitespaces with commas; see the `.replace(" ", ",")` part of the code).In a nutshell, the below splits the strings in `items` into a list, then returns the string if it appears in `myList`:

```
myList = ['apple,' 'orange', 'cat', 'dog']

df.loc[:,'matching_values'] = [", ".join([s if s in myList else "" for s in l]) for l in df['items'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", ",").split(","))]
```

This gives you something like this:

```
    items           matching_values
0   grape   
1   apple juice     apple,
2   Cat,dog         cat, dog
```

if you don't like the empty string for rows like "grape", you can fill in those values like this:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

this gives you:

```
    items           matching_values
0   grape           NaN
1   apple juice     apple,
2   Cat,dog         cat, dog
```

Comment: This works really well, Nick. Thanks so much. One thing that would be really helpful is if it matched partial strings - for example, "apple juice" in df, but just 'apple' in list, should result in 'apple' in the new column. I tried using str.contains, but seems like can't mix boolean functions here.

Comment: The best solution I can think of at the moment is to replace any white spaces with a comma, then the `split()` portion of the code will create a two-element list for items like apple juice (`['apple', 'juice']`).  I'll update the proposed answer.

Comment: Perfect! It adds a number of extra commas for all the words that are not a match to the list, but absolutely acceptable for my purposes. Thanks, Nick - much appreciated